# Add an audio file to and mkv video

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, mkv

I'm quite new to multimedia things, I'm trying to find a way to make nice screencasts, I've already been able to capture my desktop with ffmpeg:

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:0,0 -f x11grab -r 30 -s $(xwininfo -root | grep 'geometry' | awk '{print $2;}') -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec libx264 -vpre lossless_ultrafast -threads 0 -y out.mkv
```

It works pretty nice, but I'd like to add music in the background, if I add it with mencoder:

```
mencoder  -ovc copy -oac mix -audiofile track.mp3 out.mkv -o out.mp4
```

It delete the video sound, I don't want to replace it, I want to add music to my explanation, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kdenlive and add a second audio track, then remux

Comment: OMG!, I dint' know kdenlive, I'll definitely check it out!, thx, if anyone else knows how to do it in the console please let me know.

Comment: sox merge described here: http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html#lbAJ  I would split the audio out of the video the sox merge them, then mux it back together with the video

Comment: thx a lot aking that's just what I'll do

Answer (score 18):

You can install  mkvtoolnix;

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix
```

Then use mkvmerge from the installation to mux audio and video into the mkv container from the command line.

There is also a Gui tool, mkvtoolnix-gui that is a front end to mkvtoolnix.

```
sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix-gui
```

Example to mux video file called, input-video.mkv with a sound file called soundfile.mp3, creating a new muxed mkv file called output-with-sound.mkv, do the following in the directory where you have the video without audio and the audio file:

```
mkvmerge -o output-with-sound.mkv -A input-video.mkv soundfile.mp3
```

More examples including synchronization  here: http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvmerge.html

Comment: thx a lot sabacon!, I didn't know about mkvmerge, I'll use it to mux back the mixed audio

Comment: correct install command is  `sudo apt-get install mkvtoolnix-gui`

Comment: @augusto Thanks a lot, I did not notice the extra hyphen, and to know this thing was there for so long.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why mencoder didn't work for you, but you can also do the same thing with ffmpeg.  You just need to use two inputs to ffmpeg.

```
 ffmpeg -i track.mp3 -i out.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec libfaac -ab 192k final.mkv
```

I didn't try it, but I don't think you can do -acodec copy, especially since you're using two different codecs.  Just pick whatever you want in the output and add that in, its really fast compared to the video.

Comment: VLC cannot open the `mkv` file after adding or removing an audio track using this command.

Comment: Yes, mkv muxing in ffmpeg is busted. See this issue https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6037, they don't even seem to care. Ffmpeg is notorious for being slow, but this is even closing the eyes on the issue.