# How to view video file with external ac3 audio track?

Tags: video, sound, video-player, mplayer

I can listen to view the video with built-in audio (ac3) and listen to the audio track as regular sound file, but how to do these same time?

Can't see such options in Totem, Kplayer, VLC, KMplayer, Gnome-Mplayer.

Also I can't find how to do this using mplayer, though I may be lost in its huge man file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As workaround for other possible readers of this question.

Used advices from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12038/add-an-audio-file-to-and-mkv-video) to add the sound track into the video. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

And here's how to do this with VLC via the command line:

```
vlc videofile --input-slave audiofile
```

, then select the audio channel.

NB. Though not strictly related, `--sub-file <subfile>` will also load subtitles.

Comment: I've got silence when choosing a second track. While opening it as standalone track does produce sound.

Comment: Too hard to debug it from here. If that happens for one particular case, I would suggest to try a different player (see below); if it happens regularly, I would start with updating the vlc version.

Answer (score 11):

First install smplayer:

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Then open the video file and select audio > load external audio file

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Another problem: for some reason after selecting external file playback becomes extremely slow. Unloading restores normal playback. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sergii: Re-opening the thing sometimes helps (if You have save settings on in the preferences -- You probably do).

Comment: SMPlayer is awesome. Somehow VLC gives me really bad image with external audio, SMPlayer does the job well.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do this with mplayer from the command line, use the `-audiofile` flag. Example:

```
mplayer video.mp4 -audiofile sound.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to edit tracks in your container, but just load an external audio track you have, then VLC definitely have that feature.

Here's how to do that:

Choose your video file first

> ```
>  — File: Add...
> ```

and add additional audio file to it

> ```
>  — Browse...
> ```

which opens confusing the same window (itself). Here just

> ```
>  — File: Add...
> ```

to choose your audio file and confirm it by

> ```
>  — Select
> ```

button. Do not press Browse button in the second window!

Now you should have both paths to your video and audio files in one window (the first one). Now press

> ```
>  — Play
> ```

button to play video with external audio track. During playback you can choose your second audio track

> ```
> Audio — Audio Track
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In kmplayer:

1. right click on screen
2. open>load external audio
   once the audio is loaded right click again and this time  select filters and select kmp stream switcher and select your preferred audio

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Totem does have an "load external file" option for audio...

It is the second item from the top in the Audio menu (Main or Context)

Comment: Sorry, but there's definitely no such option in 2.32 shipped with my Ubuntu 10.10. It just can switch between audio tracks that already found.

Comment: @Sergii...Oops! my mistake :( ...that's what happens with lack of sleep... I got my video players mixed up. I was up all night tracking down how-to mux a text subtitle stream (.srt) into an mp4 .. I found it :)  As this is a video question here'e the link for anyone who is interested (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7212/how-to-burn-a-subtitle-track-onto-an-mp4-video-file) ...