# Loading ac3 files in VLC player

Tags: video, vlc, video-player, audio-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to view video file with external ac3 audio track?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25862/how-to-view-video-file-with-external-ac3-audio-track)

I have mkv and english.ac3 files. That mkv plays with the default audio stream which is not english. How do I load english.ac3 and play it with mkv at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can Try the this:

- Open VLC media Player
- In the *Menu > Media* choose **Open(Advanced)...**

[image]

- In the Open Media window, click in **Show more options** and **Play another media synchronously (extra audio file,...)**

[image]

- In the **"File Selection"** field add your mkv file, and in the **"Extra media"** field browse and add your ac3 file.

[image]

- Click and play, and finally go to *Menu > Audio > Audio Track* and choose The track eg:

[image]

Hope this will be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

As I usually prefer the command line, and as I'm forgetting the answer myself, and as Google has pointed me to this question first -- let me copy [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/172416/34124) here :)

```
vlc videofile --input-slave audiofile
```